# Taking a list of integers and displaying them in reverse using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

If my input is 1 2 3 the output is also coming out as 1 2 3, how do I make these numbers to display 3 2 1?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    String text = s.nextLine();


    String[] entries = text.split(" ");
    int[] nums = new int[entries.length];

     for(int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++){
        nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(entries[i]);
    }
     for(int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++){
        System.out.println(nums[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could loop through your `entries` array backwards. This would involve starting `int i` at the length of `entries` minus 1 (as that is your last index in your array - ie your last number). It would also require that you keep looping while `i >= 0`. Lastly, instead of incrementing your `i` variable, you need to decrement it. This way your counter `i` will go from the end of your loop to the start of your array (eg: if you enter "1 2 3", `i` will go from indexes: 2, 1, 0)

See example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // TODO code application logic here
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

   String text = s.nextLine();


   String[] entries = text.split(" ");
   int[] nums = new int[entries.length];

   for(int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
     nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(entries[i]);
   }
   for(int i = entries.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
     System.out.println(nums[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: If your sole intention.is to reverse the input then why cant you just reverse the `String text` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store numbers in reverse order:

```
for(int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
{
     nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(entries[entries.length-i-1]); 
}
```

If you want to just display numbers in reverse order(they'll remain same order in list:

```
for(int i = entries.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    System.out.println(nums[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  String text = s.nextLine();
  String[] entries = text.split(" ");
  for(int i = entries.length-1; i >= 0; i--) 
  {
     System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(entries[i])+ " ");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Java 8 version, here is the code

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);      
String text = s.nextLine(); 
String[] entries = text.split("\\s");

List<Integer> integers = Arrays.stream(entries)
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

Collections.reverse(integers);

integers.forEach(integer -> System.out.print(String.format("%d ", integer)));
```

`\\s` indicates 'white space' and I suggest you to close `Scanner` at the end.

Comment: If.your sole intention.is to reverse the input then why cant you just reverse the `String text` ?

Comment: @CommonMan yes if that's the case, your way is obvious